# ERROR: trytond.server timezone is not set to UTC on Windows 8

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, utc, tryton

I install all dependencies like suggest in tryton.org page, and then install tryton client and build trytond(server).

But when I try to initialise database

> C:\Python27/python.exe C:\Python27/Scripts/trytond -c C:\Python27/Scripts/trytond.conf -d  --all

I get error of the title, is like is not reconizing the UTC time

I change time to UTC like suggest this answer, restart my PC and now my timezone is in UTC.

https://superuser.com/questions/482860/does-windows-8-support-utc-as-bios-time

But is continue the error

Any idea or file that should be modify to correct this error?

**trytond.conf**

> [jsonrpc] listen == localhost:8000 hostname == localhost
>
> [database] uri == postgresql://tryton:tryton@localhost:5432/
>
> [session] timeout == 600 super_pwd == tUYUV3PebcivM
>
> [report] unoconv == "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice
>   5\program\python.exe" unoconv

**EDIT**

```
print time.strftime("%Z%z")
Hora estándar oeste, SudaméricaHora estándar oeste, Sudamérica

print time.gmtime()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=20, tm_min=15, tm_sec=33, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=9, tm_isdst=0)

print time.localtime()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=16, tm_min=15, tm_sec=33, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=9, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: `trytond`'s timezone might be different from your local timezone. Check whether there is a corresponding setting (e.g., like `TIME_ZONE` setting in django)

Comment: No, There isn't. The documentation says that use the system time...

Comment: The question you link does not say how to set Windows local timezone (BIOS issue is unrelated). What is `time.strftime("%Z%z")`? Are you sure your system timezone is UTC? `time.gmtime() == time.localtime()`?

Comment: time.gmtime() == time.localtime() is false.... See the execution of code that you suggest me... How can I correct that?

Comment: Sorry I forgot add the link see here http://imgur.com/c3QajaA

Comment: [edit] your question and include the info as text

Comment: Now I add the output as text to my question

Comment: The output says that your local timezone is not UTC. Set your system timezone to UTC.

Comment: But I confused but when I go to date and time settings I saw that my time UTC. See this capture to my date and time settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX0Kj.png

Comment: the screenshot shows that your timezone is not UTC (the UTC offset is not zero: `4 != 0`).